# Flickity - New dynamiclly created carousel not initialising

Tags: javascript, flickity

I want to insert new carousels onto my page dynamically, i have added a reduced test case of what im trying to do. The only real different is how the new carousel is being added, my test case it just a string which gets appended. but in my project, it will be an ajax request.

Anyway, as you can see, i am destroying all carousels on click, then once I've added the new carousel, i try and initialise the new one as well as the old one.

The problem is, the new one isn't effected. but the old one still works.

Any ideas and getting the new one to work too?

**Test case:** https://codepen.io/jsayner/pen/ab06bdabd3d74afc5e84cb7730d21b52

```js
// external js: flickity.pkgd.js
var $carousel = $('.carousel').flickity();


$(document).on("click", "#button", function (e) {
  $carousel.flickity('destroy');
  var template = "<div class='carousel'>"
                + "<div class='carousel-cell'></div>"
                + "<div class='carousel-cell'></div>"
                + "<div class='carousel-cell'></div>"
                + "<div class='carousel-cell'></div>"
                + "<div class='carousel-cell'></div>"
              + "</div>";
  
  $("body").append(template);
  $carousel.flickity();
});
```

```css
/* external css: flickity.css */

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.carousel {
  background: #FAFAFA;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 66%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  counter-increment: carousel-cell;
}

/* cell number */
.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(carousel-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button id="button" type="button">show carousel</button>

<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change
`$carousel.flickity();`
to
`$('.carousel').flickity();`

The variable $carousel is only the instance when you fisrt init flickity, so not work for the added element.